# cakephp validation required for files

Tags: validation, cakephp, required

I create form with input type file.
I would like validate this field when is selected file.

Rule with 'require' doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using MeioUpload for uploading files. there are several parameter to adjust the behavior to your own needs.
[MeioUpload](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/)